# How can I optimize my Linq query?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am having two tables `Room_master` and `Room_Item`

```
Room_Master => roomid - pk, roomname

Room_Item   => roomiteid - pk, roomid - fk, itemid, quantity
```

I want a list of rooms that do not have any items assigned.

I've written a SQL query as below to get the result

```
select * from room where roomid in 
(select roomid from (select SUM(quantity) as qty, roomid from Room_Item group by roomid )
as newtab where qty=0) order by roomid
```

My respective Linq query is as following

```
var roomitem1 = from ri in objEntities.Room_Item
        group ri by ri.roomid into p 
                select new { roomid = p.Key, totalitem = p.Sum(row => row.quantity) };
var roomid  = roomitem1.Where(x => x.totalitem > 0).Select(x => x.roomid);
```

The Linq query is working very fine but problem is that it takes too long time to
return the data. I have 6000 records in `Room_master` table and about 70000 records in `Room_item` table and it takes about 2 minutes to return data back to my view...

How can I optimize my Linq query so that it runs faster?

Comment: If I read your code correct then the Linq query returns room ids which have at least one item assigned where as your SQL query returns rooms with no items assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally untested:

```
objEntities.Room_Item
    .GroupBy(ri => ri.RoomId)                 // group all items by room id
    .Where(g => g.Sum(r => r.quantity) == 0)  // where the total quantity of all items for that room id is 0
    .Select(g => g.Key)
```

Should give you a list of room ids having no items assigned